# Remove decimal by VBA from a cell in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code by VBA for removing decimal from a cell (A22)
But it doesn't work.

```
Range("A22").Text = Format(Range("A22").Text, "#,###,###,##0")
```

may something is wrong. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Your question should contain what actually happens when you run your code, e.g. Run-time error '424': Object required. Then a description (sample) of the data you have in the cell, and the desired result will be required, for you to get a decent answer. You can improve your question by simply clicking on the edit button below your post.

Answer (score 0):

## NumberFormat vs Format

If you are trying to display the value in cell `A22` without decimals:

```
Range("A22").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

The cell will still contain the value with decimals, it will only be displayed without.

---

If you are trying to remove the decimals from the value in cell `A22`:

```
Range("A22") = Int(Range("A22"))
```

Now the cell contains the value without the decimals (a whole number).